# Allow data to fill only as per adjacent comma based cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

If my item is serially numbered In A3= 12,13,15,18,20,22 if I give 15,18,12 to another store and 12,20,22 to another store that I write in cell B3 and C3 respectively. then by mistake, I write 19 in place of 18 in B3 and 19 in place of 20 in cell C3 then how can I know that values are not from cell A3.

Also if possible how to come to know if one value is repeated Ex- if I type mistakenly 15,18,12,15 it show that 15 is repeated twice.
[[example sheet is here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AT2e.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AT2e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following user defined function:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IsOkay(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
    Dim v1 As String, arr, a
    v1 = "," & s1 & ","
    arr = Split(s2, ",")
    For Each a In arr
        If InStr(v1, "," & a & ",") = 0 Then
            IsOkay = "Not Okay"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
    IsOkay = "Okay"
End Function
```

It will return "Okay" if all the values in the second also appear in the first list.  It will return "Not Okay" if the second list contains items not in the first.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=IsOkay(A1,B1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Examples:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

This version of the UDF (*IsOkay2()*) fixes both problems:

1. it will treat text like *10,000* as comma-separated strings rather than single big integers
2. it will flag repeated un-matched values in the second list

```
Public Function IsOkay2(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
    Dim arr1, arr2, a1, a2, Failed As Boolean, i As Long
    arr1 = Split(r1.Text, ",")
    arr2 = Split(r2.Text, ",")

    For Each a2 In arr2
        Failed = True
        For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
            If a2 = arr1(i) Then
                Failed = False
                arr1(i) = ""
            End If
        Next i
        If Failed Then
            IsOkay2 = "Not Okay"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a2

    IsOkay2 = "Okay"

End Function
```

Comment: can You make sth special so that if we write any number twice then I will come to know that one number is twice Ex as I write in B3 12,15,18,12 then here 12 is 2 times which is wrong.

Comment: @MILANKUMAR  The **B5** problem is because Excel is taking the data to be a single REALLY BIG integer rather than a comma-separated list......................I will have to think about the second problem!!

Comment: @MILANKUMAR  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: , Sir one problem is coming that when I apply an advanced filter in large data(as a Table) it shows "#value!"

Comment: @ Gary's Student pls make Is Okay & IsOkay2 for one more cell as Example shown by you  is only for A &B column. If I required C column also and want ok &NotOkay in D column.For Example if I write in C5 230,232 it also show inD5  that it is a part of A5